# merging multiple data frames keeping the date sort

Tags: arrays, dataframe, merge

In R, I have 4 data frames with different dates and PL values:

head(Array1) gives:

```
       Dates   P&L
1 2014-10-01   900
2 2014-10-02 -3185
3 2014-10-03  3800
4 2014-10-07 -2300
5 2014-10-08  2100
6 2014-10-09  2400
```

head(array2) gives:

```
       Dates      P&L
1 2015-03-02  -6962.5
2 2015-03-03 -14237.5
3 2015-03-04   7862.5
4 2015-03-05    925.0
5 2015-03-09  -3725.0
6 2015-03-10    262.5
```

head(array3) gives:

```
       Dates   P&L
1 2014-10-08  7160
2 2014-10-09  7600
3 2014-10-10  2260
4 2014-10-13  4820
5 2014-10-15 -1500
6 2014-11-06  3030
```

head(array4) gives:

```
       Dates    P&L
1 2015-02-24   1245
2 2015-03-06  10650
3 2015-03-10   -200
4 2015-04-17  -9690
5 2015-05-15 -28740
6 2015-05-26   3970
```

I would like to aggregate all these arrays in just one array, keeping the date sort and summing when there are multiple values for one date. Can someone please help me? Joe

Comment: What programming language are you using? R?

Comment: Yes (modified). TY Psidom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to `rbind` all the data frames into a single data frame, then aggregate the values against `Dates`:

```
agg <- aggregate(`P&L` ~ Dates, rbind(array1, array2, array3, array4), FUN = sum)

agg[order(as.Date(agg$Dates)),]

#        Dates      P&L
#1  2014-10-01    900.0
#2  2014-10-02  -3185.0
#3  2014-10-03   3800.0
#4  2014-10-07  -2300.0
#5  2014-10-08   9260.0
#6  2014-10-09  10000.0
# ...
```

Or put the four arrays in a list, use `do.call(rbind, ...` to bind the data frames together:

```
lst <- list(array1, array2, array3, array4)
agg <- aggregate(`P&L` ~ Dates, do.call(rbind, lst), FUN = sum)

agg[order(as.Date(agg$Dates)),]
```